# scope bar search iPad

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, searchbar

I have to specialize a search in my iPad app, and I think to use the scope bar with the search bar. But how can I get the index of a selected scope button and base my search on it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:)